# Can I tap a land creature for mana *and* attack with it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my friend has a land-creature and he tapped it for mana, can he attack with that land-creature after?

Comment: Hi Nguyen, welcome to the site. I see from your informed badge you've checked out our [tour], thanks for doing so! I've removed the second question from your question. Please [ask it separately](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). We have a policy of only asking one question per question, except when makes no sense to do so. You can always access the previous revisions of your question (and the text I deleted) from your revision history, accessed by clicking the [edited X time ago](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/33843/revisions) link at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, he can't. A creature must be untapped to be declared an attacker, so if it's tapped for any reason—including for mana—before attackers are declared, it can't attack.

Comment: thank you very much, and if i kill it,  will it still stay on the battle field as a land or it will go to the graveyard?

Comment: That's a separate question, so it should be asked separately instead of in a comment. Fortunately, someone already did: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/when-land-becomes-creature-can-you-kill-it