# Can Gideon, Champion of Justice be exiled the moment he becomes a creature with his 0 ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Here is [Gideon, Champion of Justice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Champion%20of%20Justice%5d). After using his +0 ability to become a creature, can he be removed with something like [Final Reward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFinal%20Reward%5d)?

Comment: I am not completely sure about the status as a duplicate, as the other question was originally asked about a land that becomes a land-creature... but the exact same answers can be generically applied to any permanent that becomes a creature; so I figured it would be good to just have that question be more broad.

Comment: I thought killing and removing would be different in this case. Since when the exile spell resolves and gideon returns to be a planeswalker at the end of turn doesn't mean he'd become an illegal target?

Comment: Undid the duplicate; linking to the other question here as a related question: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/when-land-becomes-creature-can-you-kill-it

Comment: @Chris After the spell has resolved, he is no longer a target, so changing back to a planeswalker doesn't make him an illegal target.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can use [mtg:cardname] to auto-link to cards. I've updated your post to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, while Gideon is a creature, you can target him with anything that targets creatures.

After Gideon's second ability has been activated; he is both a planeswalker and a creature. This means that he can be targeted by anything that targets either one of those.

> 300.2. Some objects have more than one card type (for example, an artifact creature). Such objects combine the aspects of each of those card types, and are subject to spells and abilities that affect either or all of those card types.

At the time that you cast [Final Reward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFinal%20Reward%5d), all that matters is that he is a creature, and so he is a legal target. When Final Reward resolves, he is also still a creature and still a legal target, so he will be exiled. There's nothing in the game that cares at that time that his being a creature is only temporary.

At the end of the turn, nothing will happen because the "until end of turn" was on a creature/planeswalker that no longer exists.

Comment: A small hair-split, you cannot immediately bounce him. After his ability resolves, his controller will have priority again but once you get priority, you can send Giddles packing.

Comment: @Veskah That is true; I wasn't taking "the moment" literally in the question.